# Year extraction with datetime library for several columns

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I want to create a function that goes through my `Pandas` `Dataframe` and converts all date variables in the following format: `%b-%Y`, for example: `Jun-2017`, `Apr-2017`, `May-2017`, and so on, into the difference between the current year and the year of the date in each registry (for example: `2018 - year_corresponding_to_each_registry`).

My function is:

```
def date_to_numeric(df):
  for col in dates:
    print("Converting date variables to years: " + col, flush = True)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%b-%Y', errors = 'coerce')     
    df[col] = df[col].apply(dt.year)
  return df
```

I am having a problem in the following line:

```
df[col] = df[col].apply(dt.year)
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'year'
```

P.D. I have imported datetime library with the following line code:

```
import datetime as dt
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided in how to accomplish this in an efficient way.

> ANSWER

Thanks to @DeepSpace answer (check it below marked as **correct answer**):

```
def date_to_numeric(df):
  for col in dates:
    print("Converting date variables to years: " + col, flush = True)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%b-%Y', errors = 'coerce')     
    df[col] = 2018 - df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors = 'coerce').dt.year
  return df
```

Comment: What format do you want your *time differences* to be in?

Comment: Hi @jpp numeric integer. for example, for a registry which is: May-2017 the result would be 1 as numeric (2018 - 2017 = 1). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated even if it would have worked.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Jun-2017', 'Apr-2017', 'Jan-2015']})

print(df)

#            a
#   0  Jun-2017
#   1  Apr-2017
#   2  Jan-2015

df['b'] = 2018 - pd.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.year

print(df)

#             a  b
#   0  Jun-2017  1
#   1  Apr-2017  1
#   2  Jan-2015  3
```

This will work column wise (ie needs to be executed on each column separately) and will only work if all elements in the column can be parsed as a date. If this is not the case with your actual data you will need to take that into account (for example by passing `errors='coerce'` to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Jun-2017', 'Apr-2017', 'Jan-2015', 'i am not a date']})
df['b'] = 2018 - pd.to_datetime(df['a'], errors='coerce').dt.year

print(df)
#                   a    b
#  0         Jun-2017  1.0
#  1         Apr-2017  1.0
#  2         Jan-2015  3.0
#  3  i am not a date  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge @DeepSpace, could do it with your code lines. finally I entered this chunk in my script working perfectly: def date_to_numeric(df):
  for col in dates:
    print("Converting date variables to years: " + col, flush = True)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%b-%Y', errors = 'coerce')     
    df[col] = 2018 - df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors = 'coerce').dt.year
  return df

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd

df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format="%b-%Y")            #Convert to date object
print(df[col].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.now().year - x.year))     #Sub from current year.
```

Comment: OP would probably benefit more if you didn't write a code only answer, but elaborate a bit on your thinking

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, if i import datetime without being followed by "as dt", I receive the following mistake following your solution just after executing your "print" line: <<NameError: ("name 'dt' is not defined", 'occurred at index issue_d')>>. If I import datetime followed by "as dt", I receive the following mistake just after your "print" line: <<AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index issue_d')>> Thanks for your code.